# Google App Script connection returning error 401

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-apps-script

I'm using a google script to connect to an external API with the code:

```
  var url='https://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/XXX/orders'

  var parameters = { method : 'get',
                    headers : {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+'yyy'}, 
                    contentType:'application/json',                   
                    muteHttpExceptions:true};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,parameters).getContentText();

  Logger.log(response);
```

But why is this returning the following error?

```
HTTP ERROR 401
Problem accessing /api/v1/XXX/orders. Reason:
    Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the contentType from parameters and give it a shot.

For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the contentType and I got the same error.

Comment: Are you sending the right set of parameters? You're supposed to send a secure_auth_key in the parameters, failing which would lead to 401 error.

http://help.ecwid.com/customer/portal/articles/1166917-order-api#Parameters

Comment: I'm sending the key in the header parameter. 'yyy' in my code above.